# How can I uninstall the macports tex packages?

Tags: macports, latex

I have installed MacTex 2013 and it seems to be properly installed, except that the binaries used at are from macports.

"sudo port uninstall texlive" will not do anything. No output from the command.

"sudo port list | grep tex/" gives the following list of installed tex programs:

```
BibTool                        @2.55           tex/BibTool
LaTeXML                        @0.7.0          tex/LaTeXML
LaTeXiT                        @2.5.0          tex/LaTeXiT
biblatex-biber                 @0.9.9          tex/biblatex-biber
bibutils                       @4.12           tex/bibutils
blahtexml                      @0.9            tex/blahtexml
detex                          @2.8            tex/detex
disvf                          @0              tex/disvf
dot2texi                       @3-0-0          tex/dot2texi
dvipng                         @1.14           tex/dvipng
kde4-kile                      @2.1.3          tex/kde4-kile
kile                           @2.0.1          tex/kile
latex2rtf                      @2.3.3          tex/latex2rtf
latexdiff                      @1.0.2          tex/latexdiff
latexmk                        @4.35           tex/latexmk
luatex                         @0.65.0         tex/luatex
makejvf                        @1.1a           tex/makejvf
pTeX                           @20110314       tex/pTeX
pgf                            @2.10           tex/pgf
pgf-devel                      @2010-09-28     tex/pgf-devel
ptex-sfmacros                  @0              tex/ptex-sfmacros
rtf2latex                      @1.5            tex/rtf2latex
rtf2latex2e                    @2.0.1          tex/rtf2latex2e
rubber                         @1.1            tex/rubber
sketch                         @0.3.7          tex/sketch
tetex-frogg                    @0.4-3          tex/tetex-frogg
tetex-rechnung                 @3.10           tex/tetex-rechnung
tex-beamerposter               @112            tex/tex-beamerposter
tex-f7u12                      @dev            tex/tex-f7u12
tex-gantt                      @1.3            tex/tex-gantt
tex-songs                      @2.14           tex/tex-songs
tex-whizzytex                  @1.3.1          tex/tex-whizzytex
texlive                        @2012           tex/texlive
texlive-basic                  @26926          tex/texlive-basic
texlive-bibtex-extra           @26726          tex/texlive-bibtex-extra
texlive-bin                    @2012           tex/texlive-bin
texlive-bin-extra              @26926          tex/texlive-bin-extra
texlive-common                 @2012           tex/texlive-common
texlive-context                @26873          tex/texlive-context
texlive-documentation-arabic   @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-arabic
texlive-documentation-base     @26923          tex/texlive-documentation-base
texlive-documentation-bulgarian @19296          tex/texlive-documentation-bulgarian
texlive-documentation-chinese  @26851          tex/texlive-documentation-chinese
texlive-documentation-czechslovak @26864          tex/texlive-documentation-czechslovak
texlive-documentation-dutch    @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-dutch
texlive-documentation-english  @26760          tex/texlive-documentation-english
texlive-documentation-finnish  @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-finnish
texlive-documentation-french   @26782          tex/texlive-documentation-french
texlive-documentation-german   @26888          tex/texlive-documentation-german
texlive-documentation-italian  @26875          tex/texlive-documentation-italian
texlive-documentation-japanese @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-japanese
texlive-documentation-korean   @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-korean
texlive-documentation-mongolian @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-mongolian
texlive-documentation-polish   @26827          tex/texlive-documentation-polish
texlive-documentation-portuguese @24139          tex/texlive-documentation-portuguese
texlive-documentation-russian  @26661          tex/texlive-documentation-russian
texlive-documentation-serbian  @26818          tex/texlive-documentation-serbian
texlive-documentation-slovenian @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-slovenian
texlive-documentation-spanish  @24109          tex/texlive-documentation-spanish
texlive-documentation-thai     @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-thai
texlive-documentation-turkish  @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-turkish
texlive-documentation-ukrainian @15878          tex/texlive-documentation-ukrainian
texlive-documentation-vietnamese @21855          tex/texlive-documentation-vietnamese
texlive-fonts-extra            @26866          tex/texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-fonts-recommended      @26838          tex/texlive-fonts-recommended
texlive-fontutils              @26926          tex/texlive-fontutils
texlive-formats-extra          @26689          tex/texlive-formats-extra
texlive-games                  @26207          tex/texlive-games
texlive-generic-extra          @26700          tex/texlive-generic-extra
texlive-generic-recommended    @26785          tex/texlive-generic-recommended
texlive-htmlxml                @26926          tex/texlive-htmlxml
texlive-humanities             @25861          tex/texlive-humanities
texlive-lang-african           @23085          tex/texlive-lang-african
texlive-lang-arabic            @26822          tex/texlive-lang-arabic
texlive-lang-armenian          @20529          tex/texlive-lang-armenian
texlive-lang-cjk               @26926          tex/texlive-lang-cjk
texlive-lang-croatian          @23085          tex/texlive-lang-croatian
texlive-lang-cyrillic          @26689          tex/texlive-lang-cyrillic
texlive-lang-czechslovak       @26926          tex/texlive-lang-czechslovak
texlive-lang-danish            @23085          tex/texlive-lang-danish
texlive-lang-dutch             @25990          tex/texlive-lang-dutch
texlive-lang-english           @25990          tex/texlive-lang-english
texlive-lang-finnish           @25990          tex/texlive-lang-finnish
texlive-lang-french            @26756          tex/texlive-lang-french
texlive-lang-german            @26867          tex/texlive-lang-german
texlive-lang-greek             @26902          tex/texlive-lang-greek
texlive-lang-hebrew            @15878          tex/texlive-lang-hebrew
texlive-lang-hungarian         @25806          tex/texlive-lang-hungarian
texlive-lang-indic             @26926          tex/texlive-lang-indic
texlive-lang-italian           @26234          tex/texlive-lang-italian
texlive-lang-latin             @25990          tex/texlive-lang-latin
texlive-lang-latvian           @25990          tex/texlive-lang-latvian
texlive-lang-lithuanian        @23085          tex/texlive-lang-lithuanian
texlive-lang-mongolian         @25990          tex/texlive-lang-mongolian
texlive-lang-norwegian         @23085          tex/texlive-lang-norwegian
texlive-lang-other             @26614          tex/texlive-lang-other
texlive-lang-polish            @25990          tex/texlive-lang-polish
texlive-lang-portuguese        @25990          tex/texlive-lang-portuguese
texlive-lang-spanish           @25990          tex/texlive-lang-spanish
texlive-lang-swedish           @23085          tex/texlive-lang-swedish
texlive-lang-tibetan           @15878          tex/texlive-lang-tibetan
texlive-lang-turkmen           @25990          tex/texlive-lang-turkmen
texlive-lang-vietnamese        @22766          tex/texlive-lang-vietnamese
texlive-latex                  @26725          tex/texlive-latex
texlive-latex-extra            @26807          tex/texlive-latex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended      @26788          tex/texlive-latex-recommended
texlive-latex3                 @19447          tex/texlive-latex3
texlive-luatex                 @26718          tex/texlive-luatex
texlive-math-extra             @26720          tex/texlive-math-extra
texlive-metapost               @26926          tex/texlive-metapost
texlive-music                  @26926          tex/texlive-music
texlive-omega                  @26926          tex/texlive-omega
texlive-pictures               @26791          tex/texlive-pictures
texlive-plain-extra            @25953          tex/texlive-plain-extra
texlive-pstricks               @26865          tex/texlive-pstricks
texlive-publishers             @26831          tex/texlive-publishers
texlive-science                @26607          tex/texlive-science
texlive-xetex                  @26926          tex/texlive-xetex
xindy                          @2.4            tex/xindy
```

Does this mean I should execute "port uninstall" for each one of the above lines?

Comment: Yes, or perhaps put the MacTex path ahead on your $PATH

Comment: But I never explicitly installed all these packages. They must be dependent on "texlive".

Comment: If I execure "sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents texlive" I get no output. Nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `port list` shows *all* packages that are known to MacPorts. To get a list of packages that are actually *installed*, use `port installed`. Slower but with a few more details: `port list installed`.

As for your actual problem: Maybe the reason why uninstalling "texlive" produces no output is because the package is not installed in the first place. Try to determine a concrete binary that is interfering with MacTex and that you want to get rid of. Then determine the MacPorts package to uninstall with this command: `port provides /path/to/file`.

Comment: Hi harzbube, your answer was very helpfull. This is what I get for the "latex command":


prompt$ port provides ``which latex``
/opt/local/bin/latex is provided by: texlive-latex


So I will uninstall that package, including its dependencies...

Answer (score 2):

> sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents texlive-bin

This should do it. Just in case, do the same for texlive-common.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the same problem because I have a working MacTeX install, but then macports installed texlive as a dependency (for auctex).  Mark's comment,

> Yes, or perhaps put the MacTex path ahead on your $PATH,

prompted me to check, and sure enough, the MacTeX path was totally absent.  I have simply put it on the front of my $PATH variable and things now work as before.  I'll deal with that extra texlive installation some other time :p.

In terminal do

```
cd /usr/local/texlive
```

and then ls (list the directory) and such to follow the directories until you find your texlive binaries (e.g. latex, pdftex, etc).  Once you find the full path to them you can add them to your bash profile (see below).

Put something like this into your ~/.bash_profile file BELOW any changes made by MacPorts texlive.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin:$PATH
```

Comment: hacky as the proper path changes with time - but I see no other way to give macports path priority, except for tex.

Comment: `export PATH="\`cat /etc/paths.d/Tex\`:$PATH"` is slightly better